# React dynamic component list not updating correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/mjxrz2npzy

I am creating an app where users can click on an Add Timer button to create a limited number of custom countdown/countup timers, defined in a component CustomTimerRow.  Each row has an icon that if they click it, it will remove the timer.

I have the following parent component containing the list of rows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import CustomTimerRow from './CustomTimerRow';
import AddRow from './AddRow';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {customTimers:state.clock.customTimers}
  }; 

class ConnectedCustomTimers extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.buildCustomTimers = this.buildCustomTimers.bind(this);
    }

    buildCustomTimers()
    {
        let timerList = [];
        let index = 0;
        if(this.props.customTimers)
        {
            for(let t of this.props.customTimers)
            {
                timerList.push(<CustomTimerRow number={index++} timer={t}/>)
            }
        }
        return timerList;
    }

    render()
    {
        const elems = this.buildCustomTimers();
        const addRow = (this.props.customTimers.length < 8 ? <AddRow/>:<span/>);
        return (<div>
                    {elems}
                    {addRow}
                </div>
                    );
    }

}

const CustomTimers = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ConnectedCustomTimers);
export default CustomTimers
```

My Redux store has the following actions for the timers:

```
    case constants.ADD_CUSTOM_TIMER:
        return {...state,customTimers:[...state.customTimers,action.payload]};
    case constants.REMOVE_CUSTOM_TIMER:
        const newTimers = state.customTimers.slice();
        newTimers.splice(action.payload, 1);
        return {...state,customTimers:newTimers};
```

Everything works perfectly fine when adding rows, however when I remove a row, it always removes the last row from the list, no matter if I select a row in the middle to remove, or if I remove the first row.

When I add logging, all the way through to CustomTimers' render everything looks correct.  buildCustomTimers is returning a list of objects that I would expect to see.  But once the return happens and React does its thing, I see a different result.

Am I going about adding and removing components wrong here? I'm using both state updates and the containing parent to determine what to display but it seems like re-rendering the updated component list is not working correctly.

UPDATE: I updated the code to have the following:

```
buildCustomTimers()
{
    let timerList = [];
    let index = 0;
    if(this.props.customTimers)
    {
        for(let t of this.props.customTimers)
        {
            timerList.push(<li key={index++}><CustomTimerRow key={index++} timer={t}/></li>)
        }
    }
    return timerList;
}

render()
{
    const elems = this.buildCustomTimers();
    const addRow = (this.props.customTimers.length < 8 ? <AddRow/>:<span/>);
    return (<div><ul>
                {elems}
                </ul>{addRow}</div>
                );
}
```

But that did not change the behavior at all so I do not beleive the List and Key answer may be the correct answer (though not discounting if there is another way to do it)

Comment: do `console.log(action.payload)` and check its values.

Comment: I have and right before I return my components in CustomTimers <div>...</div> the objects that look like they will be displayed are not the ones that are in fact rendered.  For example if I add a custom timer for event type AOS, and then add a timer for event type LOS, and then remove the AOS timer (which is at index 0), all the way through to CustomTimers render everything shows that LOS is the only timer in my custom timer list, even right before returning from render.  However on the page only the AOS timer remains.

Comment: Can you by chance show an example using https://codesandbox.io/ or similar? :)

Comment: Will do, never used it so give me a bit!

Comment: Can you add your `<CustomTimerRow/>` component code?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mjxrz2npzy

Comment: and updated my original post with the link at top

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the error is in your CustomTimerRow code but when you create a list of components in a loop you must add a "key" props.
This key has to be unique.

[Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

If you try:

```
<CustomTimerRow number={index++} timer={t} key={t.eventType} />
```

You'll see that it's working. As *t.eventType* is not unique, this cannot be your definitive key, but this shows you how keys are important.

Comment: Awesome thank you!  I am confused why doing simply key={index++} didn't render the same result since the index should be unique, but instead I took your t.eventType and concatted it with index++ and yay, unique keys.

Comment: It's because "index" is not unique, it changes when your component rerender and your array length is not the same. You have to find a unique and not changing key. So you can't either concat your index with something else.

Comment: Hrm I tried using a timestamp when the row is added (which should give each element a very unique key) but that's causing some odd behavior, too.  It seems to work sometimes but then removes the wrong element other times.  But apparently the key is the trick here so I just need to figure out what works consistently.

Comment: You can check if your object have an unique property (database id for example) or if you have never the exactly same object twice you can use "object-hash" npm package, it will generate a hash of your object.

Comment: Ah I needed to update my reducer to find the index of the unique key to splice on that.  Works like a charm.  You literally kept me from going balder than I already am

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was that not update tihs.setState(...) with reomved class object, only class parennt.removeChild(...). Otherwise only js object removed and ul/li item remains.